# make attractive scrollbar compatible with all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing chat and call application in my project.

So there are 3 tabs.

1. people to chat
2. dialer to dial to particular person
3. chat / call history

in this tabs there are 3 portions.

1. header
2. chat / call / history portion.
3. tab changer navigator.

I make middle portion scrollable.

I want to make that scrollbar thinner. I don't want to use browser's default scrollbar.

For this I find "::-webkit-scrollbar" which is perfect only for chrome.

I want to apply this css to all browsers.

I find scroll plugins but I don't want to use any external plugin. I want to solve this by using jquery / css/ javascript.

is there any property or anything which can solve my issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: if there's one thing I wish someone would tell me when I started coding, is stop trying to reinvent the wheel. chances are someone already made an entire open-source project that does just that, and some Asian contributor perfected it better than you ever will.

Answer (score 0):

The `::webkit-scrollbar` pseudo element is NON-Standard and there is no way to make this cross-browser-compatible at the moment. There are good reasons why this hasn't evolved as standard yet. Just imagine some touch devices having browsers without scrollbars or with scrollbars, which are hidden by default and shown only when scrolling (to save valuable space). Custom styling would need to fit all these use cases.

Therefore I'd generally recommend you not to style the browser scrollbar with this hack. If you really need a solution, you could try [jquery.scrollbar](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/). IMHO this is no robust solution, however. It relies purely on JavaScript and may be jiggling around on some devices.

edit: further info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)